# Sqlalchemy if table does not exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wrote a module which is to create an empty database file

```
def create_database():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///myexample.db", echo=True)
    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    metadata.create_all()
```

But in another function, I want to open `myexample.db` database, and create tables to it if it doesn't already have that table.

EG of the first, subsequent table I would create would be:

```
Table(Variable_TableName, metadata,
       Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
       Column('Date', Date),
       Column('Volume', Float))
```

(Since it is initially an empty database, it will have no tables in it, but subsequently, I can add more tables to it. Thats what i'm trying to say.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you are trying to do is database migrations. You should consider looking at [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's a database migration package for python to be used with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what I intended to do. I used `engine.dialect.has_table(engine, Variable_tableName)` to check if the database has the table inside. **IF** it doesn't, then it will proceed to create a table in the database.

Sample code:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///myexample.db")  # Access the DB Engine
if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, Variable_tableName):  # If table don't exist, Create.
    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    # Create a table with the appropriate Columns
    Table(Variable_tableName, metadata,
          Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False), 
          Column('Date', Date), Column('Country', String),
          Column('Brand', String), Column('Price', Float),
    # Implement the creation
    metadata.create_all()
```

This seems to be giving me what i'm looking for.

Comment: i had to add `schema = 'dbo'` in `has_table` call to make it work on MS SQL

Comment: @lowtech In what part of the code do you add "dbo"? Currently I have problems asking about a table in MSSQL.

Comment: @vix I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Is sqlalchemy able to access the database you supplied it with? If not, it will not be able to query the table you are looking for.

Comment: @VIX `if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, Variable_tableName, schema = 'dbo')`

Comment: Using SQLAlchemy v1.2.11, ``engine.dialect.has_table(engine, tableName)`` is not there.  However ``engine.has_table(tableName)`` does the job nicely :)

Comment: meta.create_all() has an implicit conditional, it creates the table if it does not exist. If that is the case we we need this "if" ?

Comment: This is unnecessary as @Belle05's answer states, because `create_all()` has an optional parameter `checkfirst` that defaults to `True`. If set, tables are only created if they do not exist yet.

Comment: I get the following error when running your code: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 76):

Note that in 'Base.metadata' [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) it states about create_all:

> Conditional by default, will not attempt to recreate tables already
>   present in the target database.

And if you can see that create_all takes these arguments: create_all(self, bind=None, tables=None, checkfirst=True), and according to documentation:

> Defaults to True, don't issue CREATEs for tables already present in
>   the target database.

So if I understand your question correctly, you can just skip the condition.

Answer (score 40):

The accepted answer prints a warning that `engine.dialect.has_table()` is only for internal use and not part of the public API. The message suggests this as an alternative, which works for me:

```py
import os
import sqlalchemy

# Set up a connection to a SQLite3 DB
test_db = os.getcwd() + "/test.sqlite"
db_connection_string = "sqlite:///" + test_db
engine = create_engine(db_connection_string)

# The recommended way to check for existence
sqlalchemy.inspect(engine).has_table("BOOKS")
```

---

See also the SQL Alchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_table).

Comment: Yes; this worked for me. [inspect] returns a Boolean, so very easy to use in all logical flows. I also see the Warning when I try to use [Dialect].

Answer (score 11):

For those who define the table first in some `models.table` file, among other tables.
This is a code snippet for finding the class that represents the table we want to create ( so later we can use the same code to just query it )

But together with the `if` written above, I still run the code with `checkfirst=True`

```
ORMTable.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

#### models.table

```
class TableA(Base):
class TableB(Base):
class NewTableC(Base):

   id = Column('id', Text)
   name = Column('name', Text)
```

#### form

Then in the form action file:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///myexample.db")
if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, table_name):
   # Added to models.tables the new table I needed ( format Table as written above )
   table_models = importlib.import_module('models.tables')

   # Grab the class that represents the new table
   # table_name = 'NewTableC'
   ORMTable = getattr(table_models, table_name)            

   # checkfirst=True to make sure it doesn't exists
   ORMTable.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Comment: was looking everywhere for this; this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Tried that recently with SQLite. For some reason  `engine.dialect.has_table(engine, Variable_tableName)` didn't work for me, however the following worked correctly:

```py
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///myexample.db")
if engine.dialect.has_table(engine.connect(), Variable_tableName):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

engine.dialect.has_table does not work for me on cx_oracle.
I am getting `AttributeError: 'OracleDialect_cx_oracle' object has no attribute 'default_schema_name'`

I wrote a workaround function:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Engine  
def orcl_tab_or_view_exists(in_engine: Engine, in_object: str,  in_object_name: str,)-> bool:
    """Checks if Oracle table exists in current in_engine connection

    in_object: 'table' | 'view'

    in_object_name: table_name | view_name
      """
    obj_query = """SELECT {o}_name FROM all_{o}s WHERE owner = SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'current_schema') AND {o}_name = '{on}'
    """.format(o=in_object, on=in_object_name.upper())
    with in_engine.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(obj_query)
    return len(list(result)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code working for me to create all tables of all model classes defined with `Base` class

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class YourTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'your_table'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

DB_URL="mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>"
scoped_engine = create_engine(DB_URL)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(scoped_engine)
```