# Python Flask (sqlachemy) - validate database name if exists after user inputs table name into a form?

Tags: python-3.x, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a form that asks the user to input a database table name and then my app uses that table name to run a query on a MySQL database. What I'm trying to do is run an initial test on the database to see if the inputted table exists and if it doesn't then let the user know that the table name supplied doesn't exist and to try again. Currently my app opens an error stack and lets me know that the table name doesn't exit. This isn't the behavior I'm after. I want it to do is to stay on the page and then send a message to the user by highlighting the form box in red and printing the error message underneath the box. I can get this functionality to work on other fields, but can't seem to get it working for this field. This is my code in my forms.py file.

```
class RespondentForm(FlaskForm):
path = StringField('Path', validators=[DataRequired()])
tabName = StringField("Table Name (only fill out if you are not sending 'Invitations')", validators=[Optional()])
choices = [('1', 'Invitation'), ('2', 'Initial reminder'), ('3', 'Subsequent reminders')]
TypeOfMail = SelectField('Select Type of Mail', choices=choices)
test = BooleanField('Send Out Test Emails')
submit = SubmitField('Return Recipients')

def validate_path(self, path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path.data):
        raise ValidationError('Path entered does not exist, please enter correct path')

def validate_table_name(self, tabName):
    engine = create_engine('URI')
    metadata = MetaData()
    try:
        test = Table(tabName.data, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    except NoSuchTableError:
        raise ValidationError('Table name entered is incorrect, please enter correct table name')
```

The raise ValidationError works perfectly for the validate_path method, but does't work for the validate_table_name method.I'm assuming it has to do with the try accept statements, does anyone know of a function that I could use to test if a table exists on a database and returns either true or false? If there is such a function then I think my code would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I wrote a function that tests if a table exists and here it is:

```
def exists(tabname):
engine = create_engine('URI')
metadata = MetaData()
try:
    test = Table(tabname, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    return True
except NoSuchTableError:
    return False
```

and then changed my validate_table_name method to be:

```
    def validate_table_name(self, tabname):
    if not exists(tabname.data):
        raise ValidationError('The table name entered does not exist, please try again')
```

The function works well, but still no joy because for what every reason I can't get the validate_table_name method to execute. I'm definitely puzzled.

Comment: Have you tried `engine.has_table(tableName)` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053241/sqlalchemy-if-table-does-not-exist)?

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own function, but its good to know that there is one. By sadly it hasn't solved my issue. For what ever reason, when I run the code it doesn't enter the validate_table_name method. When I run the command path = form.path.data in my my route, with form = RespondentForm(), it enters the validate_path method and executes properly, but when I run tabname =  form.tabname.data it doesn't execute the validate_table_name method. Its really got me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. Not sure why this is the case, but when I declared the name of the validate-table_name() method inside my RespondentForm class I needed to name it def validate_tabname(), that is the keyword in def validate_ needed to match the field name declared. (I spent a full day on this....very frustrated considering it was such an easy fix.)

So working code was:

```
class RespondentForm(FlaskForm):
  path = StringField('Path', validators=[DataRequired()])
  tabname = StringField("Table Name (only fill out if you are not sending 'Invitations')", validators=[Optional()])
  choices = [('1', 'Invitation'), ('2', 'Initial reminder'), ('3', 'Subsequent reminders')]
  TypeOfMail = SelectField('Select Type of Mail', choices=choices)
  test = BooleanField('Send Out Test Emails')
  submit = SubmitField('Return Recipients')

  def validate_tabname(self, tabname):
    if not exists(tabname.data):
        raise ValidationError('The table name entered does not exist, please try again')

  def validate_path(self, path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path.data):
       raise ValidationError('Path entered does not exist, please enter correct path')
```

Using my self defined function exists.

```
def exists(tabname):
  engine = create_engine('URI')
  metadata = MetaData()
  try:
    test = Table(tabname, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    return True
  except NoSuchTableError:
    return False
```